# Android Applications EULA

Tags: android, eula

Is it mandatory to have EULA for free android applications on Android Market. I 'm going to upload a free android application on Android Market. Since I 'm new to the process to uploading application to android market could anyone tell me why EULA is needed ?

Comment: Because without about seventeen pages of disclaimers, in America you could probably get sued for aggravated assault if someone hits someone else on the head with their phone while your app is running.

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it says anywhere that a EULA is *needed*, but rather that they just recommend using one. That said, I'm distributing two apps on the Market and don't have a EULA for either. I'm pretty sure that Android users have to agree to a general EULA about the market before being able to download anything, and this EULA contains the general statements about not stealing and "It's not our fault if something bad happens".

Here is an example: https://web.archive.org/web/20130205134238/http://www.developer-resource.com/sample-eula.htm

Comment: In looking at the [Google Play ToS](https://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html), I haven't found anything all encompassing similar to "It's not our fault if something bad happens".  I think I will make an "in app EULA" just to be on the safe side.